# Php Include function causes whitespace and ignores style

Tags: php, html

I have a page that uses another page via the include() function. The page that requests and uses this external page has some html embeded as well as some output using the echo function. Here is an example of what I am referring to.

page Apple.php contains:

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>

<h1>I have some content here.</h1>

 <div id="format" style=" width:20px; height:20px;"><?php include("Orange.php") ?></div>

 <h2>Some more content here.</h2>
 </body>
 <html>
```

page Orange.php contains:

```
  <?php
     $astringA='blue';
     $astringB='berry';
     include("someExternalPage.php");
     echo "fruit is ".$astringA.$astringB.$externalVariable;
     ?>
```

Whenever the Apple.php is viewed in browser, only the top part of its body is shown(the part above the include function) and everything below the div box is lost and filled with whitespace. In addition the included file ignores all style that the div box has. The same is true for the Orange.php; all output below the include() function is lost. How can I fix this so that the included file will conform to the style I want for it and also to continue to output the rest of the content on the pages?

I also notice that even if I try outputing the rest of the page through php such as 
                       echo ">h2>Some more content here."; (I deliberately inverted the first ">" in the line above so that I illustrate the code here)
the included still takes precedence over the current page and thus the output is never shown.

Comment: Does someExternalPage.php exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smells like you have a hidden fatal error here.

Try using error_reporting(E_ALL) and run the page to see if you have an error...

Comment: If they don't appear after trying this, you can check Apache's logs or add `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` after this line to see the errors (if there are any) on the page.

Comment: I have tried error_reporting(E_ALL) as well as ini_set('display_errors', '1'); but I still can't find the errors. I have error reporting enabled by default so I am able to see other errors in the past on other projects.

Comment: Thanks alot. Although I had error reporting enabled the darn thing kept showing me whitespace. When I viewed the page source there was indeed some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a semicolon after the include in Apple.php. Can we see the output when you try to load `Orange.php`? It's helpful to see exactly where the flow is breaking.

Comment: You don't need the last ; before a php end tag, it's a very good practice though, but it is not required...

Comment: Learn something new every day!

Comment: That was a typo but I do have the semi colon on the original version. I am trying to get a temporary setup for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong either with someExternalPage.php or $externalVariable.

Comment: I can't access the code for someExternalPage.php. I will try to contact the other party for this.

Answer (score 0):

If someExternalPage.php is actually an external file (ie you are including a file such as http://example.com/test.php) you may need to check that you have enabled allow_url_include in your php.ini

Alternatively, please make sure someExternalPage.php exists.

Comment: Normally I would get an error or warning if the file does not exists, however right now I am not seeing either.